# FirebaseCrashlytics; Cant build Swift Project

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, cocoapods, crashlytics

I have been trying to build an existing xcode project all to no avail.

When I build it, it gives the error below: [image]

**Here are some of the things that I have done:**

1. Upgraded cocoapods to 1.10.0
2. Done `pod install`
3. Done `pod update`
4. Deleted derived data

None of these worked.

My cocoapods version is 1.10.0.

I am using Xcode Version 11.3 (11C29)

My Macos version is macOS Mojave, Version 10.14.6(18G84)

```
    Here is the Podfile:
    
    # Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
    platform :ios, '12.0'
    inhibit_all_warnings!
    
    pod 'SwiftLint'
    
    abstract_target 'Build' do
      use_frameworks!
    
        pod 'PhoneNumberKit'
        pod 'Mixpanel'
        pod 'MGSwipeTableCell', '1.6.8'
        pod 'Firebase'
        pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
        pod 'Firebase/Database'
        pod 'Firebase/Core'
        pod 'Firebase/Auth'
        pod 'Firebase/Storage'
        pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
        pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
        pod 'GoogleSignIn', '4.4.0'
        pod 'KeychainSwift', '19.0.0'
        pod 'SwiftyJSON'
        pod 'Alamofire'
        pod 'APAddressBook/Swift'
        pod 'AlamofireImage'
        pod 'NWSTokenView'
        pod 'KDCircularProgress'
        pod 'CryptoSwift'
        pod 'RazzleDazzle'
        pod 'SVProgressHUD', :git => 'https://github.com/SVProgressHUD/SVProgressHUD.git', :branch => 'master'
        pod 'CountryPickerSwift'
        pod 'SnapKit'
        pod 'Branch'
        pod 'PromiseKit/Alamofire'
        pod 'RealmSwift'
        
      target 'AppName' do
        
      end
    
      target 'ShareExtension' do
    
      end
    
        target 'Content Extension' do
    
        end
    
        target 'Notification Extension' do
    
        end
    end
    
    useStatic = true
    def supported_staticlib_pods
        return ['APAddressBook',
                'Alamofire',
                'AlamofireImage',
                'Branch',
                'CountryPickerSwift',
                'Crashlytics',
                'CryptoSwift',
                'SwiftyJSON',
                'Firebase',
                'FirebaseAnalytics',
                'FirebaseAuth',
                'FirebaseCore',
                'FirebaseDatabase',
                'FirebaseDynamicLinks',
                'FirebaseInstanceID',
                'FirebaseMessaging',
                'FirebaseStorage',
                'GTMSessionFetcher',
                'GoogleSignIn',
                'GoogleToolboxForMac',
                'KDCircularProgress',
                'KeychainSwift',
                'MGSwipeTableCell',
                'Mixpanel',
                'NWSTokenView',
                'PromiseKit',
                'Protobuf',
                'RazzleDazzle',
                'SnapKit',
                'leveldb-library',
                'nanopb',
                'Pods-Build-Content Extension',
                'Pods-Build-Notification Extension',
                'Pods-Build-AppName',
                'Pods-Build-ShareExtension']
    end
    
    post_install do |installer|
       require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/scripts/improve_pre_main_time_loading.rb")
       if useStatic
         improve_pre_main_time_loading(installer, "Build-AppName", supported_staticlib_pods)
       end
       installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
           puts "=== #{target.name}"
           if target.name == "FirebaseAuth"
               target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                   config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= ['$(inherited)', 'AF_APP_EXTENSIONS=1']
                   config.build_settings['APPLICATION_EXTENSION_API_ONLY'] = 'NO'
               end
           end
           if target.name == "FirebaseCore"
               target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                    config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= ['$(inherited)', 'AF_APP_EXTENSIONS=1']
                   config.build_settings['APPLICATION_EXTENSION_API_ONLY'] = 'NO'
               end
           end
           if target.name == "FirebaseDatabase"
               target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                   config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= ['$(inherited)', 'AF_APP_EXTENSIONS=1']
                   config.build_settings['APPLICATION_EXTENSION_API_ONLY'] = 'NO'
               end
           end
           if target.name == "AppAuth"
               target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                   config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= ['$(inherited)', 'AF_APP_EXTENSIONS=1']
                   config.build_settings['APPLICATION_EXTENSION_API_ONLY'] = 'NO'
               end
           end
           if target.name == "FirebaseMessaging"
               target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                   config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= ['$(inherited)', 'AF_APP_EXTENSIONS=1']
                   config.build_settings['APPLICATION_EXTENSION_API_ONLY'] = 'NO'
               end
           end
           if target.name == "Pods-ShareExtension-FirebaseInstanceID"
               target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                   config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= ['$(inherited)', 'AF_APP_EXTENSIONS=1']
                   config.build_settings['APPLICATION_EXTENSION_API_ONLY'] = 'NO'
               end
           end
           if target.name == "Pods-ShareExtension-FirebaseDynamicLinks"
               target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                   config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= ['$(inherited)', 'AF_APP_EXTENSIONS=1']
                   config.build_settings['APPLICATION_EXTENSION_API_ONLY'] = 'NO'
               end
           end
           if target.name == "Pods-ShareExtension-FirebaseMessaging"
               target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                   config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= ['$(inherited)', 'AF_APP_EXTENSIONS=1']
                   config.build_settings['APPLICATION_EXTENSION_API_ONLY'] = 'NO'
               end
           end
           if target.name == "SVProgressHUD"
               target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                   config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= ['$(inherited)', 'AF_APP_EXTENSIONS=1']
                   config.build_settings['APPLICATION_EXTENSION_API_ONLY'] = 'NO'
               end
           end
           if target.name == "SwiftyJSON"
               target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                   config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= ['$(inherited)', 'AF_APP_EXTENSIONS=1']
                   config.build_settings['APPLICATION_EXTENSION_API_ONLY'] = 'NO'
               end
           end
           if target.name == "RazzleDazzle"
             target.build_configurations.each do |config|
               config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.0'
             end
           end
       end
    end
```

How do I resolve these errors?

Answer (score 0):

Something about GoogleUtilities is not being linked properly.  This might solve it.

- `pod deintegrate`
- Make sure the resulting Xcode project's setting
  does not include references to GoogleUtilities - or any other pods.
- `pod install`

Comment: Thanks for answering. Please how do I carry out the second step you specified? thanks

Comment: Open the `.xcodeproj` in Xcode and search the Build Settings or even more thorough is to use a text editor and search the `.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` file.

Comment: BTW, step 2 may not be necessary - so you could try just 1 and 3 first without 2.